# Showing bad request, take a look the flowing code where is error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I  crate an API in dot-net core but update is not working properly, following are code below.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(int id, Assignment assignment)
    {
        if (id != assignment.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _learning_GpsContext.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _learning_GpsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Above code is dependent on the following entity values.

```
public partial class Assignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpectedMasteryDate { get; set; }
    public int FirstRange { get; set; }
    public int SecondRange { get; set; }

    public int GroupType { get; set; }
    public int LearningStrategyId { get; set; }
    public int TeachingStrategyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Uic { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public byte ExcludeWeekend { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Youtubevideourl { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int AssignmentTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AssignmentTypeId")]
    public AssignmentType AssignmentType { get; set; }

    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LessonId")]
    public Lesson Lessons { get; set; } 
}
```

It is not unable to get value, and it will be always redirected and showing bad request. Flowing error is showing when run through the "swagger".

> {
>     "lessons.units.course.department.govtSchoolSystems.country.schoolSystems[0].id": [
>       "Could not create an instance of type DataLibrary.Data.SchoolSystemModel.SchoolSystems. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'lessons.units.course.department.govtSchoolSystems.country.schoolSystems[0].id', line 154, position 23."
>     ],
>     "lessons.units.course.department.privateSchoolSystems.country.schoolSystems[0].id": [
>       "Could not create an instance of type DataLibrary.Data.SchoolSystemModel.SchoolSystems. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'lessons.units.course.department.privateSchoolSystems.country.schoolSystems[0].id', line 271, position 23."
>     ]
>   }

Comment: Care to share the source code for the rest of your models, mainly the `SchoolSystems`, and also the actual request you were sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should remove partial from the Assignment class if you want to be able to use it in your put method.

Second you are missing the attribute.

> #### [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using the request body.

When you use `FromBody` attribute you are specifying that the data is coming from the body of the request body and not from the request URL/URI. You cannot use this attribute with `HttpGet` requests, only with PUT, POST, and Delete requests. Also you can only use one `FromBody` attribute tag per action method in Web API (if this has changed in mvc core I could not find anything to support that).

> #### [FromRouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> Summary: Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using route-data from the current request.

Essentially it `FromRoute` will look at your route parameters and extract / bind the data based on that. As the route, when called externally, is usually based on the URL. In previous version(s) of web api this is comparable to `FromUri`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Put([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Assignment assignment)
```